# C++ vector and memoization runtime error issues

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, runtime-error, memoization

I encountered a problem [here](http://www.codechef.com/problems/COINS/) at Codechef. I am trying to use a vector for memoization. As I am still new at programming and quite unfamiliar with STL containers, I have used `vector`, for the lookup table. (although, I was suggested that using `map` helps to solve the problem).

So, my question is how is the solution given below running into a run time error. In order to get the error, I used the boundary value for the problem (`100000000`) as the input. The error message displayed by my Netbeans IDE is `RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 4s)` with input as `1000000000`. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define LCM 12
#define MAXSIZE 100000000
using namespace std;
/*
 * 
 */
vector<unsigned long> lookup(MAXSIZE,0);

int solve(int n)
{
    if ( n < 12) {
        return n;
    }
    else {
        if (n < MAXSIZE)  {
            if (lookup[n] != 0) {
                return lookup[n];
            }
        }

            int temp = solve(n/2)+solve(n/3)+solve(n/4);
            if (temp >= lookup[n] ) {
                lookup[n] = temp;
            }
            return lookup[n];

    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    int n;
    n = solve(t);
    if ( t >= n) {
        cout<<t<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<n<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It could be that you recurse to much and get a stack overflow. Use the debugger to see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt if this is a memory issue because he already said that the program actually runs and he inputs 100000000.

One things that I noticed, in the if condition you're doing a lookup[n] even if n == MAXSIZE (in this exact condition). Since C++ is uses 0-indexed vectors, then this would be 1 beyond the end of the vector.

```
    if (n < MAXSIZE)  {
     ...
    }

        ...
        if (temp >= lookup[n] ) {
            lookup[n] = temp;
        }
        return lookup[n];
```

I can't guess what the algorithm is doing but I think the closing brace } of the first "if" should be lower down and you could return an error on this boundary condition.

Answer (score 2):

You either don't have enough memory or don't have enough contiguous address space to store 100,000,000 `unsigned long`s.

Comment: I think the size of the vector is only `100,000,000`. Which would be either 400 MB or 800 MB depending on the size of `unsigned long`.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. The problem is most likely the lack of *contiguous* address space, which a `vector` requires.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly is a memory issue. For a vector, you need contiguous memory allocation [so that it can keep up with its promise of constant time lookup]. In your case, with an 8 byte double, you are basically requesting your machine to give you around 762 mb of memory, in a single block.

I don't know which problem you're solving, but it looks like you're solving Bytelandian coins. For this, it is much better to use a map, because:

1. You will mostly not be storing the values for all 100000000 cases in a test case run. So, what you need is a way to allocate memory for only those values that you are actually memoize.
2. Even if you are, you have no need for a constant time lookup. Although it would speed up your program, std::map uses trees to give you logarithmic look up time. And it does away with the requirement of using up 762 mb contiguously. 762 mb is not a big deal, but expecting in a single block is.

So, the best thing to use in your situation is an std::map. In your case, actually just replacing `std::vector<unsigned long>` by `std::map<int, unsigned long>` would work as `map` also has `[]` operator access [for the most part, it should].